# mysql, extract unique values from columns

Tags: mysql

I have this website where I would allow the user to effectively parse the mysql database. I would like to present on the website the list of possible unique values from each column and hit an execute button to retrieve the data.

Is there a way to extract the unique values from the columns in a database? quickly? Before I was thinking of having some mapping file created before hand. I would ideally like this system to be fast. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

select DISTINCT [column] from [table];

Comment: This doesn't meet the speed requirement. I assume they are asking about a way of having them precalculated in an index or something.

Comment: He does not ask about speed and indexes but only about unique values. Please don't invent parts of the question :) The speed he refers to seems to be about a "scripted solution", seems to me the author simply did not know the DISTINCT keyword in SQL... seems he gave that answer an UP, too. Now I'm just not quite happy that the later response received the UP and mine did not :( :)

Comment: what is the speed on this? what if my database is 1 million + rows

Comment: The speed is very dependant on your setup, hardware, Indexes etc. Can you provide any more information?
You can also try this and show us the Explain plan, it is usually a good starting point to assess performance.

Comment: What I take as a given: one has to have an index on all the columns that are named. That's true for any column ever named after "SELECT". Anyway, if you have that index the rest is up to your particular database, the hardware and its configuration - how much RAM is made available for certain types of cache, etc. I don't think one can give a general answer, it very much depends on the very concrete situation. One has to rely on the DB manufacturer to have implemented the best algorithm for that purpose, not much a DB user can do - if you WANT to execute that operation, you have to "pay" for it.

Comment: It now seems to go way beyond the original question, but depending on the very concrete example(!) one additional option is to keep that kind of information externally, e.g. in memcache, and update it whenever a row is added or deleted. This is only useful when insert/delete happen very rarely, but in that particular case you would safe the cost of the SELECT DISTINCT completely! Not sure it would make sense except in fringe cases, after all, for databases the DISTINCT operation has been a key feature for decades so they should all execute it as well as is possible at all by now, I'd think.

Comment: @Mörre - I didn't invent part of the question at all. Did you miss the phrase "I would ideally like this system to be fast" Of course the comment applies equally to the other answer but I thought making the point once was sufficient. To me a proper answer to this question should explain indexing strategies. If the OP genuinely doesn't know `DISTINCT` then what's the chances they are going to know about those!

Comment: @Martin - This has been answered above, hasn't it?

Comment: SMALL CORRECTION: Was I drunk? Above I wrote two sentences, of which the second one is so stupid that I have to say it: <<What I take as a given: one has to have an index on all the columns that are named. [NOW COMES THE STUPID ONE] That's true for any column ever named after "SELECT".>> I take the second one back.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name;
```